# Creating assoc record in HABTM through

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, has-and-belongs-to-many

Models:

**cities.rb:**

```
has_many :cities_users
has_many :users, :through => :cities_users
```

I have a HABTM (through) between `cities` and `users`.  I want to view all cities associated with a user.  Here's what I have and what the error is:

**users.rb**

```
has_many :cities_users
has_many :cities, :through => :cities_users
```

Controller:

```
@user = User.find(current_user.id)
@users_cities = @user.cities
```

I have written a migration that creates the JOIN table:

```
create_table "cities_users", :id => false, :force => true do |t|
   t.integer "user_id"
   t.integer "city_id"
end
```

This is my error (relating to second line of controller code):

```
uninitialized constant User::CitiesUser
```

I'm having similar problems **creating** a city that is associated with a user too.

Many thanks.

Comment: Can you show your `cities_user` model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create new model if you want to use `has_many :through` association.
Please, consider using `has_and_belongs_to_many` for direct many-to-many connection with no intervening model.

For any details you can read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has-many-through-and-has-and-belongs-to-many.